# Unable to play local file video in html5 player in ionic 3 angular

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am unable to play video from local file of android storage in ionic angular v3. Here is the console error.

`Not allowed to load local resource: file:///data/user/0/app/files/downloaded_files/videos/lu-1.mp4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After along struggle, I fixed the path. I found from the webview plugin. I just copy the code from webView cordova plugin and paste in my class component.

`window.WEBVIEW_SERVER_URL + url.replace('file://', '/_app_file_')`

It is replacing the `file://` with `/_app_file_`

Comment: Kudos for returning to your own issue and leaving insights for others if they come across the same issue!